# How to create a column in oracle with object data type

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g

I'm a web developer. I'm from Javascript and Typescript background. A few days ago I decided to learn JDBC with Oracle. I've created a very basic JDBC project with JavaFX and Oracle. (Actually I'm trying to mimic Microsoft Azure). I've a Date field also which will get its value from JavaFx  built-in Datepicker component. Here is some useful information:

**Columns in table: mybranches**

1. branch_name varchar(50)
2. branch_created_on date
3. branch_pulled_from varchar(50)

The problem is the 2nd column i.e. the `branch_created_on` field.

Here's my java code: **DataService.java**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
...

public class DataService {
    Connection con;
    PreparedStatement pstmt;
    
    static String branch_name="";
    static LocalDate branch_created_on;
    static String branch_pulled_from="";
    
    DataService() {
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","tiger","scott");
        }
        catch(Exception e){ 
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
    
    public void getValue() {
        branch_name=AddNewBranchRecord.branchNameTextField.getText();
        branch_created_on=AddNewBranchRecord.datePicker1.getValue();
        branch_pulled_from=(String) AddNewBranchRecord.combo_box_1.getValue();
    }
    
    public void putValue() {
        System.out.println("Branch name: "+branch_name);
        System.out.println("Branch created on: "+branch_created_on);
        System.out.println("Branch pulled from: "+branch_pulled_from);
    }
    
    public void insertRecord() {
        getValue();
        try {
            pstmt=con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO mybranches (branch_name,branch_created_on,branch_pulled_from) VALUES (?,?,?)");  
            pstmt.setString(1,branch_name);
            pstmt.setObject(2,branch_created_on);
            pstmt.setString(3,branch_pulled_from);
            pstmt.execute();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DataService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

The output of `putValue` is also correct:

> Branch name: 1000-test
>
> Branch created on: 2020-02-11
>
> Branch pulled from: master

But the moment I call `insertRecord` method, I get this exception:

> SEVERE: null
>
> java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type
>
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
>
> ...

This exception is not there If I remove that date column from the database table as well as java code. I'm extremely sorry If I'm asking a stupid question. I'm from Angular and React background. Please correct me.

Comment: Probably doesn't support `LocalDate`. You can try `java.sql.Date.valueOf(localDate);` to get a `java.util.Date`. I'm sure there is a way to store `LocalDate` via some sort of custom converter, which would be better, but maybe just not out of box.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider. You're right. But I tried both. But still getting the exception.

Comment: Dates have to be custom. It can be two years ago or two years hence from now.

Comment: Why do you want to use `setObject` rather than `setDate` or `setTimestamp`?

Comment: @AlexPoole. I'm glad you asked this question. Actually I've already faced this.

Question. `pstmt.setDate(2,branch_created_on);` is giving me `error: incompatible types: LocalDateCannot be converted to Date`. Because JavaFX DatePicker is `LocalDate`. 

Ans. don't use `java.sql.Date` continue using `LocalDate`. You can use `pstmt.setObject(2, branch_created_on)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really want to be using `setObject()`.

> `pstmt.setDate(2,branch_created_on);` is giving me error: `incompatible types: LocalDateCannot be converted to Date`.

You can combine this with @Christopher's comment to do:

```
pstmt.setDate(2,java.sql.Date.valueOf(branch_created_on));
```

With that change and the Java variables hard-coded (rather than from a picker) that compiles and runs, with output:

```
Branch name: 1000-test
Branch created on: 2020-02-11
Branch pulled from: master
```

and in the database:

```
select * from mybranches;

BRANCH_NAME                                        BRANCH_CREATED_ON   BRANCH_PULLED_FROM                                
-------------------------------------------------- ------------------- --------------------------------------------------
1000-test                                          2020-02-11 00:00:00 master
```

Comment: Oh. Great. Out of my instinct I tried typecasting it to (Date). But didn't work Let me try yours.

Comment: Sir, This worked. :-)
I was trying, `pstmt.setDate(2,(Date)branch_created_on);`

Comment: Sir, I'm so sorry for wasting your time. I'm new to Java and JDBC. I thought the problem is the way I created my table columns and their data types.

Comment: Learning isn't wasting time *8-)